# Error with case sensitive names in Ubuntu 14.04 and Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, zend-framework, case-sensitive

This question has been asked many times and I have gone through most of them and still haven't found an effective way to solve this.

Here's the problem.

I mainly develop using Zend Framework 1.12 on Windows and deploy applications to my VPS Ubuntu 14.04. Most of the times it works fine but since I started using sub-folders I am having issues. When I upload to Ubuntu VPS I am getting class not found errors.

I know this is because Linux is case sensitive.

To illustrate the problem below is the directory structure of my project.

In this structure I get class not found errors when I call class "**Default_Form_User_Login**".

[image]

This works fine on Windows.

And I can easily solve this in Linux by renaming the "**forms/user**" directory to "**forms/User**".

**But I want to use lowercase names for all my directories. Is there a way to solve this problem without renaming the "user" directory?**

I have also tried **mod_spelling** module of Apache and it works but I might not have access to enable this on certain servers, so this isn't a proper solution for me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can add upper case symlink to your lower case folder: ln -s dir/user dir/User

Comment: I guess you could write your own autoloader that doesn't follow PSR-0 - why are you so set on lower case folder names?

Comment: @TimFountain Thanks for the suggestion. I am keen on lower case names because I have quite a few projects developed by other developers and which follow lower case naming.